# How to test a react app using reactotron on a physical iOS device?

Tags: ios, reactjs, testing, reactotron

I'm a QA tester and i'm currently testing a react mobile app, using reactotron among other tools.

The thing is I can't make it work with a physical iOS device. I had no problem using it with a virtual android device.

For reference I'm using a MacBook also. I haven't found much on Google, which is strange.. only suggestions on how to test in development stage.

Is there any guide or something to get to connect reactotron with the iphone?